# Access agent hostname for a build variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've got release pipelines defined that have worked. I've got a config transform that will write a API url to a config file (currently with a hardcoded api url).

What I'd like to do is be able to have the config be re-written based on the agent its being deployed on.

eg. if the machine being deployed to is TEST-1, I'd like to write `https://TEST-1.somedomain.com/api` into a config using that transform step.

The `.somedomain.com/api`  can be static.

I've tried modifying the pipeline variable's value to be `https://${{Environment.Name}}.somedomain.com/api`, but it just replaces the API_URL in the config with that literal string (does not populate machine name in that variable).

Being that variables are the source of value that is being written to configs during the transform, I'm struggling to see another way to do this.

some gotchas

- Using non yaml pipeline definitions (I know I saw people put logic in variable definitions within yaml pipelines)
- Can't just use localhost, as the configuration is being read into a javascript rich app that would have js trying to connect to localhost vs trying to connect to the server.

I'm interested in any ways I could solve this problem

Comment: Are you using classic pipelines or YAML pipelines?

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem, @Ronnyek did you find solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

`${{Environment.Name}}` is not valid syntax for either YAML or classic pipelines.

In classic pipelines it would be `$(Environment.Name)`.

In YAML, `$(Environment.Name)` or `${{ variables['Environment.Name'] }}` would work.

Comment: Except setting the variable `API_URL` to `https://$(Environment.Name)/api` in my release pipeline doesn't actually cause the config transform to insert the actual environment name. This is what its currently doing with that set that way

```
"API_URL": "https://$(Environment.Name)/api",
```

Comment: You're not really describing the scope at which you're trying to resolve the variable. Posting additional detail could help.